# Python Tkinter: Attempt to get widget size

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, size, tkinter

I am trying to find the size of my window by using the `winfo_geometry()` function but it ends up returning `1x1+0+0`
I have also tried `winfo_height, winfo_width` but i keep getting `1`

#### CODE

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry('400x600')

print (root.winfo_width())
print (root.winfo_height())
print (root.winfo_geometry())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are trying to get the dimensions before the window has been rendered.

Add a `root.update()` before the `print`s and it shows the correct dimensions.

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()

root.geometry('400x600')

root.update()

print (root.winfo_width())
print (root.winfo_height())
print (root.winfo_geometry())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to find the actual width within the initial procedure to display a window is to use `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()`. It shows you the parameter that is *requested* to tkinters geometry manager. Example:

```
root = tk.Tk()
print(f'''width is {root.winfo_width()},
requested width is {root.winfo_reqwidth()}''')
root.mainloop()
```