# Tkinter: how to fix the window opening position while letting the width and height wrap the content

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to my `Tkinter` window to open at the center of the screen while not having to enter the width and height of the screen myself.
I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14910894/3551661) great answer but it requires specifying the dimensions of the window.

Instead of this
[image]

I want to get a result like this:
[image]

Comment: by your application being centre of the screen do of the screen do you mean one of the corners being central or the actual centre being in the centre?

Comment: I added screenshots to explain the question further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`winfo_width`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_width-method)/[`winfo_height`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_height-method) (or `winfo_reqwidth`, `winfo_reqheight`) to get the window size.

```
def center_window(win):
    # win.update_idletasks()
    screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()
    width = win.winfo_reqwidth()
    height = win.winfo_reqheight()

    x = screen_width / 2 - width / 2
    y = screen_height / 2 - height / 2
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
```

used `winfo_reqwidth`, `winfo_reqheight` in case the window is not fully set up.

or you can call [`update_idletasks`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) before call `winfo_width` / `winfo_height` to carry out geometry management.

Comment: This doesn't give me exactly what I want. It gives me this https://ibb.co/nmWbvk (check the updated question for screenshots that further explain what I want.

Comment: @A_Matar Try and call `root.update()` right before the first call to the `winfo` methods. There's an issue about widget height and width and how they're stored, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13327659/7051394

Comment: @Rightleg Yeah it worked, if you may edit the original answer, so that I can mark it accepted

Comment: @A_Matar, Added `win.update_idletasks()` line to the code in the answer and mentioned about update_idletasks.