# Python : Retrieve ttk.Frame size

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm tring to get Frame's size - but no luck.

in code below- I got both answers ,"0" ( line marked with ***)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
w = '400'
h = '100'
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))
root.configure(bg='lightgreen')

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("Hello")


testframe = ttk.Frame(root)
testframe.grid(row=0, column=1 )

label1 = ttk.Label(testframe, textvariable=txt)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

print(testframe["width"], testframe.cget("width"))   ***This line

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `update` method needs to be called first, so as to have the widget rendered.
If it is not, then its width is equal to zero.
This is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13327708/7051394).

Now, the problem with `testframe['width']` is that it's only a *hint* of the actual width of the widget, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3950766/7051394).

The following code will ouput `32`, as expected.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
w = '400'
h = '100'
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(w, h))
root.configure(bg='lightgreen')

txt = StringVar()
txt.set("Hello")


testframe = ttk.Frame(root)
testframe.grid(row=0, column=1 )

label1 = ttk.Label(testframe, textvariable=txt)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Modified lines
testframe.update()
print(testframe.winfo_width())

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

The frame widget will not have a size until it gets mapped on screen. There is a Tk event raised when a widget is mapped so the right solution for this example is to bind the `<Map>` event for the frame and do the print statement in the event handler function.

```
def on_frame_mapped(ev):
    print(ev.widget.winfo_width())

testframe.bind('<Map>', on_frame_mapped)
```

Comment: can you explain what is the diff between your solution and using `update()` ?

Comment: Update runs the Tk event loop once to flush the queued events. Setting up a window involves a number of events and if the map event is a result of some other event being handled then it will not be queued until later. Binding to the Map event ensures you request the information from the widget once the information is accurate. Without this you are hoping that the right events got processes and the widget may or may not actually be in the correct state. In general the use of update in a tk script indicates a poor design decision and some event should be used instead.

Comment: can you  please refer for an examples to understand the use of `<Map>`?

Comment: Tk bind manual describes the events. Map being at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm#M13